# What is the reason of using jest with sonarqube

Tags: jestjs, sonarqube

I have just started out on javascript testing and it already looks to be a vast concept. I was studying how sonarqube is used in conjunction with jest to produce test reports.

I don't understand the purpose behind using sonarqube with jest. Can' jest do the task by itself what sonarqube is supposed to do? I read on jest documentation that it can produce code coverage result, then for what sonarqube is used?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest is a tool for running unit tests.  It will produce the raw code coverage data file.  The code coverage data file is used by SonarQube to determine the resulting human-readable coverage data to display.

Neither of them use the other.  SonarQube uses the data produced by Jest.

Comment: So you mean the purpose of combining sonarqube with jest is just to convert reports produced by jest into something graphcal, is it?

Comment: Jest, like similar tools for other languages, produces the raw data in a standard format, and SonarQube processes that data to produce an overall coverage percentage.